# success message does not fire on successful submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

My validation errors displays but if I fill the field in and submit, nothing happens. I am guessing something is wrong in the jQuery but I can't seem to see it. I have also included the code for the add-news-ajax.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $( "#form1" ).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'functions/add-news-ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: form,
                })

                .done(function (data) {

                    if (!data.success) {

                        if(data.errors.n_title) {
                            $( "#title-error" ).hide().html(data.errors.n_title).fadeIn();
                        }

                    } else {

                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                })

                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

here is the php from the ajax call:

```
$errors = array();
$response = array();

if(empty($_POST['n_title'])) {

    $errors['n_title'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Title required </div>";
}

$response['errors'] = $errors;

if($errors) {

    $message['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = "fail";

} else {

    $message['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Success, yay!";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Do you get any error logs?Try adding `console.log(data);` after                     `.done(function (data) {` line.

Comment: Get: Object {errors: Array(0), message: "Success!"}

Comment: If this is what you get in data, how can you access `data.success` ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But I have edited my original question to include the php in the hope that it will further clarify

Comment: I already did and posted the response? `Object {errors: Array(0), message: "Success!"}` So, it seems to be working fine as it console logs the success message but the code after my else statement doesn't execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data.success` would be `undefined` in case you do not have a success field in your `data`. Hence you would never hot the else case where you write `alert("success");`

Probably you would want the done method to be as follows

```
done(function (data) {

                    if (data.message != "Success!") {

                        if(data.errors.n_title) {
                            $( "#title-error" ).hide().html(data.errors.n_title).fadeIn();
                        }

                    } else {

                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Hmm. That works. But why wouldn't `  if (!data.success) {` work? It is defined in my php code `$message['success'] = true;` and `$message['success'] = false;`

Comment: `$message['success'] = false;` - this is an assignment. It does not at all imply `success` was part of the data you get back as evident in you log message.